# How to send a query in a variable using laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6, laravel-query-builder

I have this function to register my users

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'apellido' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'idop' => ['required', 'string', 'max:6', 'unique:users'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        'cedula' => ['required', 'int'],
        'fecha_nacimiento' => ['required', 'date'],
        'fecha_ingreso' => ['required', 'date'],
        'extension' => ['required', 'int'],
        'movil' => ['required', 'int'],
        'tel_hab' => ['required', 'int']
    ]);

}
```

I would like to send this query in a variable ($generos) to make a select

```
$generos = DB::table('tbl_lista_generos')
            ->select('id','genero')
            ->get();
```

How could I do that?

Comment: what will be error you are getting dude?

Comment: I don't have an error... I don't know how to send the query to the view for make my select

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the variable from `controller` to `view` using below ways:

**Way1**

```
$generos = DB::table('tbl_lista_generos')
            ->select('id','genero')
            ->get();
return view("index", compact("generos "));
```

**Way2**

```
 $generos = DB::table('tbl_lista_generos')
                ->select('id','genero')
                ->get();
 return view("index", ["generos" => $generos]);
```

**Way3**

```
 $generos = DB::table('tbl_lista_generos')
                ->select('id','genero')
                ->get();
 return view("index")->with(["generos" => $generos]);
```

> On your view file::

```
 <select name="genero">
  <option value=''>select</option>
   @foreach ($generos as $genero)
     <option value="{{ $genero->id }}">{{ $genero->name}}</option>
   @enforeach
</select>
```

Comment: thanks! this works with another pages... but I need the name of the route view from register in laravel.. do you know which is? instead of index what should I  put? I'm working in the view of register in laravel

Comment: You can use view("register")->with(["generos" => $generos]);

Comment: where do I have to put this function? in my function validator? or I have to create another function to put on it

Comment: What is the name of your view where you want to send the variable?

Comment: I'm working on the view of register in laravel... so I didn't create the view... the view is in the framework

Comment: You can execute this command `php artisan route:list` this will give you the list of all routes then you can use the require view

Comment: I saw it... the name is empty

Comment: What could I do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209008/discussion-between-sehdev-and-oscar).

Answer (score 0):

by the comments, you want to send the result of the query to the view. So,

In your controller function do:

```
return view('generos.index', [
      'generos' => DB::table('tbl_lista_generos')->select('id','genero')->get()
]);
```

In the view:

```
<select class='' name='select_form_generos'>
<option value=''>select genero</option>
@foreach ($generos as $genero)
     <option value='{{ $genero->id }}'>{{ $genero->genero}}</option>
@enforeach
</select>
```

Hope it helped!

Comment: I got an error with this............. syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting elseif (T_ELSEIF) or else (T_ELSE) or endif (T_ENDIF) (View: C:\laragon\www\bduproject\resources\views\auth\register.blade.php)

Comment: I modified the  "@enforeach" for "@endforeach".. because but nothing